# how to find the time at which last byte of the http request has been reached web server

Tags: time, byte, navigation-timing-api

I want to find the time at which the final (last) byte of the Http request has been reached the Web Server using Java. I have tried it using JavaScript using Navigation Timing API with some predefined attributes.

But I want it using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to GET your object using Sockets in Java. And read the input stream byte by byte. In this way you could capture the rough time to last byte.